# How to get reference of an open form from a class

Tags: c#, forms, reference, multiple-forms

Just some short background information:
I have been coding VB.Net and PHP for at least two years (self-taught), so please excuse me if my terminology and coding habits aren't exactly top-notch. I will improve based on your comments!

Ok so I currently have a login form that is set as the startup object in Program.cs. This is where I make a new instance of the login form and pass it by reference to the FormInstances class (in Misc.cs).

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Blah{
    class Program{
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();

            var LoginFRM = new Login();
            LoginFRM.ShowDialog();

            if(LoginFRM.LoginSuccessful == true) {
                FormInstances.LoginForm = LoginFRM;
                Application.Run(new MainForm());
            }else{
                Application.Exit();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my code in Misc.cs:

```
namespace Blah{
    public static class FormInstances {
        public static Form LoginForm;
    }

    public class Misc{
        FormInstances.LoginForm.txtTest.text = "test";
    }
}
```

However I am getting this error:

'Form' does not contain a definition for 'txtText' and no extension method 'txtText' accepting a first argument of type 'Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I fix this error, are there easier ways to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base class Form doesn't contain a textbox named 'txtText', you need to declare the exact type of the form, not the generic base class

```
namespace Blah{
    public static class FormInstances {
        public static Login LoginForm;
    }

    public class Misc{
        FormInstances.LoginForm.txtTest.text = "test";
    }
}
```

As a side note, why do you need to keep the whole Login form stored? If you just need to know if your user has been logged or not then you could just store a boolean variable obtained from the property `LoginSuccessful`

Comment: I think I've fried my brain coding too much today, my goal was to convert my VB.Net project to C# (Done most of it using [this converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)) 
Thanks for fixing that but I do have more errors to fix before checking if it works during runtime. Also, regarding why I'm storing the whole login form, it's because I need to access more than just that textbox, there are a lot more textboxes. This was just an example of what I needed help with.

Comment: In any case, I would suggest to create an ad-hoc class to keep your login information. This will be more manegeable in future and will free the resources associated with the form that could be closed if there are no more reference active.

Comment: Ad-hoc class? I've never heard of that, do you have any examples of what it looks like and it's usage?

Comment: Just a class with properties where you store the info actually present in your Login form textboxes and (if you need it) other info related to your user (like LastAccessTime, PasswordExpiresInDays and so on) An instance of this class should be created when you press OK on the login form and after validation, then the instance is retrieved from the Login form and is passed to whatever code needs it. But this is too broad to explain in all gory details here. Better resolve one problem at a time.